# iOS, first page in the UIScrollView enable landscape orientation and the second page disable the landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, landscape

There are one UIScrollView and it has two pages, the first page in the UIScrollView I want to enable landscape orientation and the second page in the UIScrollView I want to disable the landscape orientation,now I am use this code as below,but it work not perfected,the second page will horizontal screen and then portrait screen:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [ITNotificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleDeviceOrientationDidChange) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
- (void)handleDeviceOrientationDidChange{
    if(isFirstPage){
        //landscape code
    } else {
        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Every answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Just see the code as below.

AppDelegate.h file:

```
@property (nonatomaic, assign, getter=isNeedRotation) BOOL needRotation;
```

AppDelegate.m file:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (self.isNeedRotation) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

yourUIViewController.m file:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.mainScrollView) {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)ITUIApplicationDelegate;
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < screen_width) {
            appDelegate.needRotation = YES;
        } else {
            appDelegate.needRotation = NO;
        }
    }
}
```